# Adding a SSD drive to an exisitng dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I have an existing dual boot system Ubuntu 12.04 LTE and Windows 7 on a 1TB disk.
This is partitioned as 50gb for Windows, 50gb for Linux and the rest as shared storage.

I would like to add an SSD drive to improve speed would it be possible/ easy to move the existing Windows and Linux partitions to the SSD?

Or would it be better to reinstall Linux alone on the SSD and still dual boot using the Windows 7 partition on the existing drive?

Comment: How big is your SSD? Ubuntu is very flexible and there are several approaches.

Comment: Not bought it yet but probably will go for around 128GB.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Live Linux distro

```
dd if=/dev/olddisk of=/dev/newdisk bs=2048
```

after successful boot, mount old disk somewhere in linux and use it as data storage

Comment: This will not work, as the old disk is much bigger than the new disk.

Comment: doesn't matter, it will copy first 2x50 GB, the rest will be cut (data partition will be damaged, but you can fix it or resize it) and the data will be accessed from the old disk one

Comment: Who says these partitions are located at the start? And OP will end up with an invalid partition table. Big no. -1.

Answer (score 0):

divide ssd and use it bootable for both os  it help you to increase speed on win7 and ubuntu and use 1 TB drive for storage try to reinstall os, it will help both os to setup correctly on new SDD, moving os may not work as fresh.